# Ошибка CSRF token missing при загрузке фото в CKEditor

Tags: django, ckeditor

Всем привет. Подскажите, настроил Django CKEditor для flatpages. Редактор работает, а фото загружать не хочет.  Ругается на CSRF токен. Ошибка происходит при попытке загрузить файл.

Ошибка:
[09/Feb/2023 12:10:40] "POST /ckeditor/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2506
Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /ckeditor/upload/

Настройки settings.py:

```
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = '/ckeditor/upload/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
 'default': {
 'toolbar': 'Full',
 'height': 500,
 'width': 900,
 'extraPlugins':'codesnippet',
 },
}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам в форму в  шаблоне где вы загружаете картинку надо добавить
`{% csrf_token %}`

Это сделано для безопасности от самого Django чтобы никто не смог кроме вас и вашего сайта добавить к вам данные

Всё это должно выглядеть так:

```
<form action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Comment: Я проверил шаблон, который использует модуль ckeditor, там в форме прописан csrf_token.

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста код с шаблоном и вьюхой, ориентироваться только на ошибку сложновато

Comment: Это происходит в админке или у вас в шаблоне?

Comment: Обновил первое сообщение. Шаблон и въюха используется из модуля ckeditor, я только заполнил настройки и урлы.

Comment: В админке я создаю flatpages, загружаю фото и получаю такую ошибку к терминале.

Comment: Возможно понял ошибку, поменяйте местами в urls path('admin/', admin.site.urls) и поставьте его в самый конец, после ckeditor

Comment: Это не помогло. Также я изменил url на path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')), и получил новую ошибку TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

Comment: обновите ваш urls.py в вашем вопросе

Comment: Я нашел в чем ошибка, неверно указал MEDIA_ROOT. Сейчас все работает. Большое спасибо тебе за помощь!

Comment: Без проблем тогда выдели мой ответ как верный)